# Tkinter - Columns of equal weight are NOT equal width

Tags: python-2.7, layout, tkinter

I have a Tkinter Toplevel window with three columns. All three columns are configured to have equal weight. Inside column `0` and `2` are sub-frames, inside which are `Listbox` widgets. Inside column `1` is a set of buttons. For some reason, despite the fact that my 3 columns have equal weight, these Listboxes 'force' their columns to occupy more space.

I've written,

```
window.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(2,weight=1)
```

But I get:

[image: Unequal Sizes]

I've also given column `1` weights of 3 and 5, but it still remains small. However, having done this, it *seems* that columns `0` and `2` have some minimum size, then after *subtracting* that from the real width, the leftover width is used and divided by weight.

Is this a bug? Is there something I need to do to my lists? Might I be forgetting something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a bug. `weight` determines how extra space is allocated. It doesn't make any guarantees about the size of a row or column.

If you want columns to have a uniform width, use the `uniform` option and make them all be part of the same uniform group.

```
window.columnconfigure(0,weight=1, uniform='third')
window.columnconfigure(1,weight=1, uniform='third')
window.columnconfigure(2,weight=1, uniform='third')
```

Note: there is nothing special about `'third'` -- it can be any string as long as it's the same string for all three columns.

Comment: Sweet! Works great; didn't realize that! Wish I could find these details in places like http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/grid-config.html